# NetBeans 7.4 Random Hangs At "Starting Modules"

Tags: netbeans

I am a mentor for a FIRST (usfirst.org) Robotics Team Rotoraptors (http://rotoraptors.webs.com/) and we are using NetBeans (7.4) to create the program for this year’s robot (we chose Java over LabVIEW [i.e. G] and C++). We keep running into the same issue w/ NetBeans:

1. We install NetBeans and all requiste plug ins from FIRST
2. We start programming and all is well
3. Randomly we go to start NetBeans and it hangs on the "Starting Modules" stage.
4. We are not adding any other modules, updates, or other software. (The laptop we are using is dedicated to programming our robot, so it does not need anything else beyond what we are able to run before the hang up.
5. We always end up uninstalling then reinstalling NetBeans, after which it runs for awhile until hanging up at the same "Starting Modules" step again
6. After reinstalling NetBeans we are able to open the same Java project that we were working on before we saved it and turned of the laptop.
7. I cannot put any related events or triggers to the issue. It just happens at random.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated by me and the kids on the team.

James Lightfoot

Answer (score 0):

Next time please create a threaddump, a sampling snapshot of NetBeans (using JVisualVM from your JDK) aand attach it to a new issue at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/
Do not forget to attach the IDE log too

Perhaps one of the plugins causes a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Most recently I have  added to NetBeans j2me  plugin , then after installation of related J2ME  sdk it started stick on that forever "starting modules.." 
I simply uninstalled that j2me sdk outside  and netbeans now starts ok   again.

Answer (score -1):

I use from netbeans 8.02 on windows 7 and my net beans hang constantly and recently i fixed hanging problem just with renaming "component" folder name of netbeans in following path ...AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\Windows2Local

when hanging occurred again